# Delete and re-enter data in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I delete data from my Firebase database the entry successfully deleted. But when I want to add same entry again then it is not going to be entered. Need help.

```
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { 
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.child(code).exists()) { 
            progressDialog.dismiss(); 
            Toast.makeText(Champion_Insert_Activty.this,"Entry Already present in database",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            return; 
        } else databaseReference2.setValue(di);
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean, and update your original post with your code.

Comment: Drew i want to say that i have some data in database i delete the entry now i want to re enter the same data how it is possible

Comment: @Drew  databaseReference2.setValue(di); by using this i insert data. now i delete this entry but when i again try to  insert same data that i delete. that data is not showing in database

Comment: It sounds like you have a problem with either code that you wrote or manual steps in the [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). If it's about code, please share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If it's a problem with steps in the console, please provide the steps to reproduce in a list.

Comment: FrankvanPuffelen    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
         
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.child(code).exists())
                {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Champion_Insert_Activty.this,"Entry Already present in database",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                else
                    databaseReference2.setValue(di);

Comment: @FrankvanPuffeleni use this to insert data

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen    now which listener i should add to delete specific data??

Comment: I added the code from your comment. Please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42375752/edit) link under your question for adding information to your question in the future.

Comment: @WaqarMughal why are you using `databaseReference` to check the data and `databaseReference2` to insert it? Please note that your code will check this path: (where your `databaseReference` is) --child--> (`code` value), but insert value into `databaseReference2`. It might help if you mention what those two values is

Comment: the databasereference is find the parent node and databaseref2 become its child in this way i can save from duplicate entries at parent level

Comment: it just like a is my database b its child now every new entry become child of b   so i need to check thats why i use 2 references